# inconvertible types: cannot cast android.view.View to androidx.webkit.WebViewCompat how do I use androidx?

Tags: java, android

**Code**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.webkit.WebSettingsCompat;
import androidx.webkit.WebViewCompat;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        WebViewCompat web = (WebViewCompat) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettingsCompat settings;
        web.addJavascriptInterface( new WebHandler(this), "Android");
        web.loadUrl("https://google.com/");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

what am I suppose to do I've tried googling and I don't know how to set the webview as the main activity